# What niche is PRResearch supposed to fill that the other APS journals don’t already cover?

Tags: publications, journals, physics, open-access

I read the description of the [new journal PRResearch](https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/welcome) on the APS website, but I am still confused.
APS publishes specialized journals, including PRA/B/C/D/E, for each major branch of physics, and journals with a broader scope and large impact, such as PRL and PRX.

My main question is:
How is PRResearch standing in comparison with the specialized and lower impact PRA/B/C/D/E and the broader and higher impact PRL and PRX?
What niche is it supposed to fill?

On one hand, PRResearch is multidisciplinary as PRL/PRX, and both PRResearch and PRX are full open access with publication charges, whereas the other APS journals are not full open access but only have open access options.
On the other hand, as it is written on their website:

> The acceptance criteria for PRResearch are aligned with those of other long-established journals in the family, such as Physical Review A, B, C, D, and E.

Comment: They probably want to get those papers funded by grants that mandate Open Access publication. For my funding agencies, arXiv deposition (which is compatible with APS journals) is enough, but I guess some agencies demand the final version to be Open Access too.

Comment: Hasn't the second half of your question already been discussed here, in your very own question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/155005/advantages-or-disadvantages-of-submitting-to-the-new-aps-open-access-prresearch  I suggest you remove that part.

Comment: @Miguel You can have this with PR[A-E] as well.

Comment: @user151413 PR[A-E] are not compatible with Plan S https://www.coalition-s.org/addendum-to-the-coalition-s-guidance-on-the-implementation-of-plan-s/principles-and-implementation/

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist They also don't end with an R, but neither is something Miguel mentioned.

Comment: @user151413 I'm sure Plan S was what Miguel intended to refer to with the word "mandate."

Comment: What is the reason of this edit? Why asking about the IF is not allowed??

Comment: @sintetico: Because, as already explained, we cannot and do not want to predict impact factor. Such a question has many of the problems of [shopping questions](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3658/7734) in particular that there is no objective answer and that this site is not suitable as a database (in lack of a better term) for such information.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Physicist are used to make predictions, all the time. Why one would not want to predict the IF? Is it not politically correct? It is not a shopping question, I am asking for an educated guess. If you think this question goes against the website rules, please explain in details.

Comment: @sintetico: Asking to predict or even state current IF is a shopping question as per the current definition as it asks to assess an individual journal. It does not matter whether you ask for an educated guess or even something objectively measurable (such as current IF) here. If you want to debate this further, please take it to [meta].

Comment: what is the definition of shopping question? Maybe you have your own personal subjective definition of shopping question?? asking about a prediction about a measurable quantity is not a shopping question!

Comment: @sintetico: It is defined in [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/7734). And yes, this is primarily authored by me, but its purpose is to reflect the current community consensus as a status quo on which to base discussions as well as provide a FAQ. If you disagree with that, you have to suggest something else on [meta] and it has to get accepted by the community as reflected by votes.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Which funding agencies mandate "Plan S"?

Comment: @user151413 https://www.coalition-s.org/funders/

Comment: @sintetico Some questions about measurable things are shopping questions.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Yes, I had seen that, and I am not convinced: It says "endorse" it. That's doesn't mean "enforce". For instance, the EU is listed, but AFAIK they only insist on green open access, rather different from plan S and not requiring a pure open access journal.  I'd like to see an organization which right now actually enforces publishing in pure OA journals only.  Or are you saying this is going to come and that's why there is PRR?  (This is certainly not what Miguel said.)

Comment: One year later, the rules haven’t changed and the above instructions still stand: If you want to dispute these rules, take it to [meta].

Answer (score 3):

APS clearly intends for Physical Review Research to be less selective than PRL/PRX, as they elucidated in two volume 1 editorials:

[M. Thoennessen: "Editorial: Introducing *Physical Review Research*"](https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.1.010001)

> We are launching Physical Review Research to achieve three main objectives: (1) to cover the entire range of topics in physics and related fields, including interdisciplinary and newly emerging areas of research, (2) to offer an attractive option for all authors who prefer or are required to publish in fully open access journals, and (3) to align its quality standards and selection criteria with those of the other long-established topical journals in the family, such as Physical Review A–E, Physical Review Applied, Physical Review Fluids, and Physical Review Materials.

[R. D'Souza, J.-W. Pan, N. Spaldin, and J. J. Liétor-Santos: "Editorial: *Our vision for Physical Review Research*"](https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.1.010002) in volume 1:

> Within the Physical Review family, Physical Review X provides an open access journal showcasing the most selective papers in pure, applied and interdisciplinary physics. Now, Physical Review Research will complement this title by providing a fully open access title with rigorous peer-review standards and with the same acceptance criteria as Physical Review A through E, Physical Review Applied, Physical Review Fluids, and Physical Review Materials. Our goal is to establish a publication that offers the same experience and quality that we value and trust, while increasing authors’ choice within the Physical Review portfolio. As such, we welcome authors of quality manuscripts not accepted by Physical Review X or Physical Review Letters to seamlessly transfer their work to be considered for publication in Physical Review Research.

Hence I would expect its initial impact factor (expected to arrive in June 2021) to be more aligned with the specialized journals, than with the flagships. But as [you've already heard](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/155006/17254) it is hard to tell exactly where it will end up.